# Implementing a simple feedback form in JS

Tags: javascript, webforms

How do I implement the feedback form that the following sites have?:

http://foodoro.com/
http://www.heyzap.com/

(look at the left center.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably checkout the [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) or similar library for this sort of effect. There are heaps of great tutorials and plug-ins out there.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this code in github

https://github.com/lorenzoongithub/getsomefeedback

as a template / boilerplate.
It should be quite easy to adapt to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Start by looking into jQuery.  It's pretty nice for stuff like this.

http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/jquery-tutorials-for-designers/

The first example on there shows a simple way to at least get a sliding panel.  It's not exactly what you want but it gives you an idea of what jQuery can do and maybe how you'd achieve what you want.

Edit:  Here's a direct link to the sliding panel demo on there...

http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/jquery/simple-slide-panel.html